# golang HTML charset decoding

Tags: go

I'm trying to decode HTML pages that are *NOT* utf-8 encoded.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312">
```

Is there any library that can do that? I couldn't find one online.

P.S Of course, I can extract charset and decode the HTML page with goquery and iconv-go, but I'm trying not to re-invent the wheels.

Answer (score 3):

Golang officially provides the extension packages: [charset](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html/charset) and [encoding](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/encoding/htmlindex).

The code below makes sure the document can be parsed correctly by the HTML package:

```
func detectContentCharset(body io.Reader) string {
    r := bufio.NewReader(body)
    if data, err := r.Peek(1024); err == nil {
        if _, name, ok := charset.DetermineEncoding(data, ""); ok {
            return name
        }
    }
    return "utf-8"
}

// Decode parses the HTML body on the specified encoding and
// returns the HTML Document.
func Decode(body io.Reader, charset string) (interface{}, error) {
    if charset == "" {
        charset = detectContentCharset(body)
    }
    e, err := htmlindex.Get(charset)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if name, _ := htmlindex.Name(e); name != "utf-8" {
        body = e.NewDecoder().Reader(body)
    }

    node, err := html.Parse(body)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return node, nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[goquery](https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery) may meet your needs. e.g.:

```
import "https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"

func main() {
    d, err := goquery.NewDocument("http://www.google.com")
    dh := d.Find("head")
    dc := dh.Find("meta[http-equiv]")
    c, err := dc.Attr("content") // get charset
    // ...
}
```

more operations can be found with the [Document](https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery/blob/4126223a86db8598275b29db04d511cfdab67cf1/type.go#L17) struct.